# Can anyone help with an improper integral.

Tags: integration, contour-integration

I'm stuck with the following integral
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-az^{2}}}{e^{-b-iz}-1}dz$$
It seems to me there exists a clever contour which encloses the pole at $z=ib$ while being somehow equivalent to the real line. Maybe someone has any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you want a semi-circle contour...

Comment: Actually, that's a lot of residues we'll have to sum over if we do a semi-circle contour.  Note the poles occur every time $e^{-b-iz}=1$

Comment: Semi-circular cannot work as the integrand diverges at say $z=i\infty$. And, you're right there are a lot of residues!

Comment: Aha!  Do a rectangle with height of $2\pi$.  :D

Comment: One method that will definitely work is: expand the denominator into a geometric series (assuming $b>0$, say) and integrate the resulting Gaussians. This will give a series as the answer.

Comment: In fact, I think this will give $I$ in terms of a $\theta$ function.

Comment: The thing is that this integral raised from the series you are talking about) It was something like $\sum_{n\geq0}\exp(-an^{2}-bn)$, then I used Hubbard-Stratonovich transformation $\exp(-an^{2})=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi{a}}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp\Big(-\frac{y^{2}}{4a}-iyn\Big)dy$, then summed the geometric series and here I am.) I think that I shall reject this approach and try to write the sum in terms of Jacobi Theta functions then&